# Русский язык, qstring и unicode

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, unicode

У меня возникла проблема с кодировкой символов в qt проектах на visual studio. Если в вкратце в проектах с qt у меня появляется ошибка в `std::u32string temp = U"Русский язык";` но если я заместо *Русский язык* вставлю что то на английском ошибки пропадает и если я к примеру создам консольный проект и вставлю туда эту строку ошибок не будет, ошибки происходят непосредственно от компилятора. Я работаю в visual studio в связке с qt

Вот самый простой код в котором происходят ошибки

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <clocale>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::u32string str = U"Хай";
    return 0;
}
```

и вот ошибки

```
Ошибка  C2001   newline в константе
Ошибка  C2143   синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "return"
```

Comment: Какая ошибка?..

Comment: Ошибка  C2001   newline в константе
Ошибка  C2143   синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "return"

Comment: Я бы проверил две вещи. Что кодировка в файле - UTF-8 (в VSCode можно посмотреть), и что в компилятор передается флаг `/utf-8` (какая у вас система сборки?).

Comment: как понимаю msBuild

Comment: То есть вы просто в VS создали проект, и его билдите? Посмотрите в его свойствах, там где-то галочка есть под этот флаг.

Comment: Нет я создал Qt empty aplication для того чтобы не было лишнего кода в основном проекте ошибки теже. Да в общем какой бы я проект с qt не создал все повторится

Comment: ...Вы понимаете, что *"Нет я создал Qt empty aplication"* совсем не добавляет ясности? Если вы его не в visual studio создали, то где? Расскажите подробнее.

Comment: да я создал в Visual studio но прежде я установил дополнение Qt VS Tools и настроил его после чего в шаблонах проектах появилось все связанное с qt в том числе Qt empty aplication. с помощью qt я создал gui для своего приложения этот gui вполне рабочий

Comment: Я смог подключить все элементы к коду трудности возникли при изменить текста label потому что функция изменения текста принимает только Qstring но для записи русского текста в Qstring надо воспользоваться методом, я перепробовал множество, все методы которые я испробовал вызывали эти же ошибки позже я  узнал про ` QCoreApplication::translate` он может принимать индексы символов в кодировке utf 16 и больше к примеру _\u0068_ это английская буква h с русскими символами это тоже работает но чтобы узнать индексы символов надо русский текст сохранить в utf 16

Comment: Ясно. Вы проверили кодировку и флаг, про которые я написал?

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку, проблема была в кодировке файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение**

Чтобы исправить в Visual studio нужно `файл > сохранить как > возле кнопки сохранить есть стрелочка надо нажать на нее > сохранить с кодировкой > под надписью Кодировка найдите в списке Юникод (utf-8 c сигнатурой) > OK`